# How to Separating Two Objects that were never merged

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

Hi I am having an issue trying to figure out how to unmerge two objects that weren't even merged to begin with.

I'm creating a 3D character and have made the body. I then added a cube using (Shift+A) to add the new cube shape then off to the side started to make and form the left hand and am using the mirror affect as well so it's the exact same on the other side. Now I haven't merged the two object at all, yet when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> to highlight the Hand object it highlights both the (hand) and the (main body).

I can't move the hand I finished to the arm of the body part to the character I'm creating, instead both the body and the hand move together whenever I try to move the hand anywhere around the grid.

I have looked at videos and read articles to figure out how to have them both as separate objects. I have tried to hit <kbd>P</kbd> to un-join them doesn't work, I have tried to hit <kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the island of the hand but doesn't work.

I am fairly new at Blender but getting the hang of it so far I'm just stuck in trying to have both object move freely on their own so I can move the hand to the body and join them but instead both the hand and the body move together and I don't know what to do.

Please can you help with this I'm doing this for a friends company and need this project done by next week but this issue is holding me back.

Thank you.

Comment: Read Cegaton's answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name

Comment: When you added the cube were you in Edit mode or Object mode?  If you added it in Edit mode, then it became part of the object you were editing.  Select a vertex of the cube and press Ctrl-L to select all linked parts.  You should then be able to use P to separate them.