# How to separate two meshes in one object

Tags: objects

I added two torus objects, and when I click one of them, it also selects the other. They both share the same node thing. I want to delete one of them, but it keeps on deleting the other with it. I can't even undo placing the second torus without removing the other.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155

Answer (score 5):

Go into *edit mode*, press <kbd>P</kbd> and press *By loose parts*

Answer (score 3):

Go into edit mode and selecting the entire one torus by moving your mouse over the one and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>. Then press <kbd>P</kbd> which brings up a menu called *separate*, then just click on *selection* and it should separate them into two objects.