# What does this triangle icon mean and how can I add another one?

Tags: interface

[image]

Can I add another one? Because the plus sign just opens up the list.

Comment: that icon in the "outliner" represents a mesh object in your scene... add another mesh, you get another icon... curve objects have a different icon, and lamps, cameras, too...

Comment: Why do you need another one? What did you  expect when pressing the plus sign which is acting as opening heirarchy?

Answer (score 6):

That triangle indicates that your object is a **[Mesh Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/introduction.html)**.

Each time you add a new mesh object in **Object Mode**, it will be listed in the outliner:

[image]

Objects that are not meshes will appear with different icons:

[image]

If an object is parented to another, then the parent-children hierarchy will be reflected on the outliner:

[image]

If you switch to **Edit Mode** and add a new mesh, that mesh will be part of the active object, and it will not be added as a new object in the outliner:

[image]

To read more about the outliner visit: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html?highlight=outliner

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155