# How can I select and move only one primitive?

Tags: selection-tools, object-mode

I have a model which currently consists of two basic primitives.  I want to select and move only one of the shapes, but while in object mode it seems to be treating them as one object.  Must I switch to edit mode and select every vertex of the one primitive or is there an easier way?

**Edit**:  I should note that my end goal is to carve one shape by doing a boolean difference between the two.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting pieces of a mesh into a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object)

Comment: do you have two objects? or one object with two primitives in it?

Comment: @David, therein lies the question.  I don't know how to distinguish that, but iowaqas and cegaton's advice below fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have joined 2 objects then you will need to access each one of them by going to *Edit Mode*

Once you are in *Edit Mode*, hover your mouse over the primitive you want to select and press <kbd>L</kbd>.

You will be able to select a single primitive of your choice.

Comment: Thank you.  This solves part of the problem.  I can now easily select only the one shape, but blender is still not treating them as separate objects in the scene.

Comment: In **Edit Mode**, select the parts of a mesh you want to separate into a new object use 
 **P** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object