# How to stop objects moving together

Tags: modeling

I've added a sphere into my project and it moves with the other object in my project!

[image]

How can I stop this? Now and in the future, as I'm relatively new to Blender.

Comment: You have Proportional Editing turned on. Also, when you want to add an independent object make sure you do not have anything selected. If you add an object with another selected they become joined.

Comment: Read the following link to understand the difference on adding objects in **edit mode** and **object mode**: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155

Comment: Also: a cylinder is very different than a sphere...

Answer (score 9):

The circle and the different movement speed tells me that you have proportional editing enabled by accident. In the old days, this was only available in Edit Mode for meshes, now it's available in many places. You are using it in Object Mode.

Blender goes through your selected objects and checks whether any other objects are within this sphere (shown as a circle) put around all your selected Object Origins, in your case a cylinder. If it finds any, they get moved, rotated or scaled proportionally with your selection depending on what you do. Shortcut is <kbd>O</kbd>. You can disable it here:

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added an object while having another object selected. This joins them as one. (Pressing "A" selects All or de-selects all which can be helpful before you add an object if you aren't sure if anything is selected before adding another
 object). You also probably have proportional editing turned on based on the circle which denotes the vertices affected while in this mode.
[image]

Comment: True Haunt_House

Comment: Sorry, deleted my old comment too soon. Usually I wouldn't add an answer, but the select theory isn't really true and PET is the only culprit in this case.