# How to move a selected mesh in to another collection in editmode?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edit-mode

So right now i have a couple meshes in the 3d view that I want want to move into another collection. When I am in object mode and select it all the meshes are highlighted. So when pressing m and move it moves all meshes. How do I select only one mesh and move?

Comment: You can't move only parts of an object into other collections. Separate them first

Answer (score 1):

An object can be made of many connected or unconnected meshes. Creating a new mesh in edit mode will not make it a new object, but will be part of the [Active Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/active_element.html#in-object-mode)

You need to separate those meshes into different objects before they can be part of different collections.

To separate parts of a mesh and turn them into a new independent objects (with their own unique name and pivot point), use the **separate** function (pressing <kbd>P</kbd>) and choose if you want to separate by selection, unconnected parts or materials.

Read: [Why can't objects in Edit Mode have their own name?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155)