# Noob question. Join/separate object

Tags: objects, edit-mode, workflow, object-mode

Why can't I also separate two object while in **Object Mode** (while to join two objects, you must go into **Object Mode** and not into **Edit Mode**) but I have to go to **Edit Mode** to do that? Am I using wrong workflow, method a way to do that? Looking at it from wrong perspective?

Comment: Joined objects are joined at geometry level (vertices if you prefer), so you need to go in edit mode which is at vertices level too.

Comment: To explain a bit more: 2 objects A and B have 2 geometries. When joined to A, all geometry is now inside A and B no longer exists. So you need to dig into A to retrieve what was B (and separate it).

Comment: Yes, I think you're looking from wrong perspective. In order to separate objects you need some geometry to separate selected which can be only in Edit mode. In order to join objects you need selected objects which is present only in Object mode

Comment: @lemon I think I understand that: If they are joined, for example If I want to clip an ear from the monkey head object, the blender doesn't know where the ear begins or skull finishes, so in that case I need to go into edit to tell him what my definition of ear is (pure monkey)...  But the thing is, two objects are not joined "physically", they are not touching (pyramid and sphere). I want to delete just one and leave the other. But when I select one of them, the other gets selected too. Is your answer still the same?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56154#56154

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes, very helpful. Thanx

Comment: thanks for comments guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the "join" (ctrl+J in Object mode) and "seperate" (P in Edit mode)

You can think an object as a grouping of mesh data with a name. Which mode you need depends on what you want to do:

What join does: Takes the selected "objects" (therefore use object mode) and merges the mesh data from the selected objects into one single "object"

What separate does: Takes the selected vertices, edges and faces (therefore use edit mode) and writes them to a new "object" (which is different from that you are currently in.

So for example join (as in ctrl+j) doesn't make sense in edit mode since you already are in a single object. However if you want to make seperately selectable and modifiable groups of vertices, edges and faces then you could use "vertex groups"
Equally seperate (as in "P") doesn't make sense in Object mode, because for that operation you need to tell blender what vertices, edges and faces you want to seperate.

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Thanks..  It seems easier to Blend than I thought it would be, but concepts and perspectives (or whatever it is that makes Blender what it is) are not really intuitive to me and I need to work on it to grasp it fully...