# Every Mesh İs Moving Or Editing

Tags: mesh

Hi ı not using blender very much but ı know something about using. Yesterday ı wanted to make wheel for just fun but when ı duplicate something and wants to move my all meshs moving not ı selected what can ı do for it? Thanks for reading anyway ı hope you can help me ıf you cant no problem :)

Comment: your question is hard to understand but if you mean that your whole mesh is moving instead of some selected vertices, maybe disable the Proportional Editing option

Comment: I have a feeling  that you need to understand the difference between creating objects in edit mode and in object mode. Read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56155/92768