# Not able to add a curve, the Add menu only lets me add meshes

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am brand new to Blender.

I want to add a Curve Circle so I pressed <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to add it, but the popup *Add* menu only lets me add meshes.

How can I add other object types?

Comment: When you say you can only add meshes, do you mean that curves aren't there, or you can't add anything else (ex: Lights, Text, Image, Empty, etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are trying to add a curve while editing a mesh in *Edit Mode*. Meshes and curves are different kind of objects and cannot be combined.

Curves can't be added to a mesh object, and meshes can't be added to a curve object.

Exit *Edit Mode* and you will be able to add a curve as a different object. Press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>  to go to *Object Mode* to see full *Add Menu*

Blender has different kinds of objects, all of them have different and unique characteristics and cannot be combined into objects of a different kind:

- Meshes
- Curves
- Surfaces
- Metaballs
- Text objects
- Lattice

Also see related [Why can't objects in Edit Mode have their own name?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name)

Comment: You might want to read the following related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155