# Sub menu gone from Add menu

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I don't know what I did but I can not find the sub menu. I need to add an UV Sphere.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have deleted all vertices in *Edit Mode*, and now you're still in *Edit Mode* of that object.

This menu adds meshes to existing mesh inside the *Edit Mode*. Press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>  to go to *Object Mode* to see full *Add Menu*

Comment: I delete nothing! I hide the layer.

Comment: Well, this menu adds meshes to existing mesh inside the edit mode. Press tab to go to Object mode to see full add menu

Comment: :O yessssssssssssss. I find them again. Thank you.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos where do you get this symbols from? Do you have a preset of shift and tab icons?

Comment: @Crantisz I shamelessly copied some from some meta post, [this one came up on quick search](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users). I have since setup them all up using a bunch of snippets and canned comments using https://www.quickaccesspopup.com for ready access

Comment: @Crantisz I don't know if he knows them by heart or uses some overview, but you can find all them for example here: [HMTL Standard named character references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references) and you enter them (if for example you have the decimal value 8633 like Duarte used) **&#8633;** or convert the decimal value to hex value 21B9 (as in the link) and enter **&#x21B9;** so either **ampersand, number sign, decimal value, semicolon** or **ampersand, number sign, x, hex value, semicolon**