# Why is my subdivision applying to other mesh?

Tags: mesh

I applied the subdivision to the toilet and i'm trying to add a cube but it comes already with the subdivsion[image], what is it?

Comment: My guess is that you added the cube while in edit mode, thus making blender count it as a part of the same object as opposed to a separate object. Always add new objects in _Object Mode_. If you want the existing cube to be its own object, select it all in edit mode and press P (separate) and pick "By Selection". You will have to remove the subdiv modifier from the new object if you do it this way, though.

Comment: Yes! that was it, i knew it had to be something little, but it had me struggling 30 mins. thank you!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name